# Angle but not straight line preserving mapping from $\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: geometry

I am considering mappings $f\colon\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$. I am looking for a mapping $f$ that preserves angles but not straight lines. The inversion with respect to a circle has this property but is not defined on the whole plane.

Comment: What do you mean by a mapping that does not preserve straight lines ?

Comment: Have a look at conformal maps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map

Comment: Note that straight line is also an angle...

Comment: @dmitri That's not really true - you might be thinking that we could characterize straightness by saying we get a $\pi$ angle at every point, but a circle looks just like a line if we only try measuring the angles it cuts around points on it. (And any smooth curve works too - angles are a rather weak and local property so don't define straightness as you are hoping)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [conformal maps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map), as [lisyarus](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/135314/lisyarus) already pointed out in [a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885905/angle-but-not-straight-line-preserving-mapping-from-mathbbr2-rightarrow-mat#comment5959303_2885905).

Note that you might be better off considering your plane as $\mathbb C$, the [plane of complex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_plane), instead of $\mathbb R^2$. That's because many basic complex-valued functions are conformal by default; see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conformal_map#Complex_analysis) for details. So depending on what exactly you want to achieve, there is quite a wide variety of functions to choose from. On the other hand, if you have very specific requirements in a small area (a topological disk, as opposed to e.g. a few isolated points), then thanks to [analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) that small area will likely already define your mapping for the whole plane.